# Plot for binary variable effect on Linear regression

Tags: r, plot, panel-data

I am a new R user and wanted to ask a question I have. I want to graph the effect of legalization of marijuana (dummy with 0 and 1 values for each 50 states of the US) on various crime rates. I want to create a graph with the PanelView package and have gotten to this point till now -

```r
panelView(panel,
          propcrimerate ~ cmpdecr + pop18to24 + pop25to44 + pc_inc_ann + unemp + pov,
          index = c("stateno","year"), 
          outcome.type="continuous",
          type = "outcome", 
          main = "Property Crime Rate & Legalization", 
          theme.bw = TRUE)
```

Although I am getting a graph, I am not able to get one where the treatment variable, in this case cmpdecr in my model, is making the lines change from black to blue at the exact time spot in my graph. I am using a panel data.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you are happy with my answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly defined the option `type="outcome"`, inducing the package to plot your outcome over time, rather than the treatment status. The correct way to do this would be:

```
library(panelView)
data(panelView)
panelView(turnout ~ policy_edr,
          data = turnout,
          index = c("abb","year"), 
          type="treat",
          main=paste("Treatment Status over time"))
```

Or, specifically for your case,

```
panelView(data=panel, 
          propcrimerate~cmpdecr+pop18to24+pop25to44+pc_inc_ann+unemp+pov,
          index = c("stateno","year"),
          type = "treat",
          main = "Property Crime Rate & Legalization",
          theme.bw = TRUE)
```

Note that `type="treat"` is the standard option, so you can also leave that out.